# MKMapView setRegion isn't constant

Tags: iphone, mkmapview, region

I'm setting my MKMapView region inside the viewWillAppear: so that the map displays the good region right as soon as the user sees it:

```
[mapView setRegion:region animated:NO];
```

The fist time I do it, I get the region trimmed like so:

[image]

Then from there on, when I set **the exact same region**, I get something like this:

[image]

**The 2nd screenshot is what I want to get from the start**. My guess is the first time I set the region, the mapview isn't fully loaded or something along these lines. Any pointer of what I should do to fix this?

**EDIT:** This is probably related: adding an annotation to the mapView before a first call to viewDidAppear is made isn't working either. The pinView just doesn't show up. How can I make sure the map view is ready to be used within viewWillAppear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I stumbled upong [this thread](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/15810-mkmapview-needs-time-think.html) that suggested to add a delay to the `setRegion:` call (if you require to call it within the viewWillAppear method anyway). Kinda silly, but it works.

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [self performSelector:@selector(centerMap:) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.01];
}
```

I'm really curious as of what the mapView is missing to do the proper recentering without this delay.

Answer (score 1):

Issues have been reported regarding the setRegion method some time ago, I don't know if they've been fixed since then. Take a look at the following post on the Apple Dev Forums:

https://devforums.apple.com/message/57488

Comment: good pointer. That setRegion odd behavior bug might be my issue. But still couldn't find a fix :(

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried making the call from the [MKMapViewDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapViewDelegate_Protocol/MKMapViewDelegate/MKMapViewDelegate.html) mapViewDidFinishLoadingMap message?  Perhaps this is late enough to get the region right?

Comment: putting the call in mapViewDidFinishLoadingMap is equivalent of putting in viewDidAppear (in which it works every time). I want the region to already be set when the view appears to the user.

Comment: I added my setRegion code to this method but the method isnt being called.  I thought it was called automatically?